# Axios.crate devuelve Error: Provided config url is not valid en nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, axios

estoy intentando personalizar una url para poder hacer un llamado mediante fet a la api de mapbox geocoding. Necesito crear un enlace que esté formado del siguiente modo:
https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/Escobar.json?limit=5&language=es&access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibmR1cmUxMiIsImEiOiJja3lzejV6d3cxOHFpMnBveTluc3FoYjZjIn0.K38DJjgVScufkMKyRVERCA
Para ello estoy utilizando el método de axios.create, pero cada vez que ejecuto mi código, estoy obteniendo el error de Provided config url is not valid. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const axios_create = async (lugar = 'Pehuajo') => {
    try {
        // Petición http
        const instance = axios.create({
            baseURL: `https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${ lugar }.json`,
            params: {
                'limit':5,
                'language':'es',
                'access_token':'pk.eyJ1IjoibmR1cmUxMiIsImEiOiJja3lzejV6d3cxOHFpMnBveTluc3FoYjZjIn0.K38DJjgVScufkMKyRVERCA'
            }
        });
        const respuesta = await instance.get();
        console.log(respuesta.data);
    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }
}
axios_create();
```

El error completo es:

```
/Users/pablondure/Desktop/Node/05-clima-app/node_modules/axios/lib/core/Axios.js:40
    throw new Error('Provided config url is not valid');
          ^

Error: Provided config url is not valid
    at Axios.request (/Users/pablondure/Desktop/Node/05-clima-app/node_modules/axios/lib/core/Axios.js:40:11)
    at Axios.<computed> [as get] (/Users/pablondure/Desktop/Node/05-clima-app/node_modules/axios/lib/core/Axios.js:136:17)
    at Function.wrap [as get] (/Users/pablondure/Desktop/Node/05-clima-app/node_modules/axios/lib/helpers/bind.js:9:15)
    at Busquedas.ciudad (/Users/pablondure/Desktop/Node/05-clima-app/models/busquedas.js:31:41)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async main (/Users/pablondure/Desktop/Node/05-clima-app/index.js:17:13)

Node.js v17.4.0
```

Comment: Tú código me funciona perfectamente. Por cierto,  por motivos de seguridad, nunca publiques tus llaves de APIs.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta! No se entonces en donde está el error. Porque cada vez que ejecuto node, me encuentro con el error de Provided config url is not valid, esto no sucede cuando envío la url ya generada directamente.

Comment: Puedes poner el código de error completo en tu pregunta Pablo? Tal vez nos dé pistas para ayudarte.

Comment: Listo, agregado! Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: El inconveniente era la versión de axios. Estaba trabajando con axios 0.25.0, la cual me retornaba dicho error. Hice un downgrade a la versión 0.21.4 y el código funcionó perfectamente.

Comment: Hay bug reportado en github:
https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4407
https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4424

Comment: Oh wow, excelente, puedes ponerlo como respuesta dando una explicación para que la gente pueda saber qué es lo que está pasando si se encuentran con el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El inconveniente era la versión de axios. Estaba trabajando con axios 0.25.0, la cual me retornaba dicho error. Hice un downgrade a la versión 0.21.4 y el código funcionó perfectamente.
Hay bug reportado en github: github.com/axios/axios/issues/4407 github.com/axios/axios/issues/4424